# How can I avoid ExpressJS misinterpreting routes?

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I am building a RESTful API using Express. I have several modules, which get combined in a `Router`, which is the loaded by the app like so:

*./user/User.js:*

```
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', variousMiddleware, login);
router.get('/:id', variousMiddleware, getUserDetails);
router.put('/:id', variousMiddleware, updateUser);

module.exports = router;
```

*./app.js:*

```
var app = express();

var routes = express.Router();
var User = require("./user/User.js");

routes.use('/user', User);

app.use('/v1/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers
...
```

So, when I perform a `POST /v1/user/login` request, or a `GET /v1/nonexisting/randomness`, everything works correctly.

However, when I perform a `GET /v1/user/login` or a `PUT /v1/user/login` request, Express routes these as if they were `GET /v1/user/:id` and `PUT /v1/user/:id` respectively, instead of throwing 404 as I would expect it to.

I figure that Express interprets the `login` part of the route as being a valid value for the `:id` parameter in these routes.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required result is achievable by making the route specification unambiguous:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', variousMiddleware, login);
router.get('/:id([a-f0-9]+)', variousMiddleware, getUserDetails);
router.put('/:id([a-f0-9]+)', variousMiddleware, updateUser);

module.exports = router;
```

By defining the range of acceptable values for ID we avoid the misinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `GET /v1/user/login` and `PUT /v1/user/login` are being handled by your '/v1/user/:id' routes is you haven't set up a PUT or GET handler for `'/login'`.  You've only set up the POST handler.

If you change it to:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', variousMiddleware, login);
router.get('/login', variousMiddleware, login);
router.put('/login', variousMiddleware, login);
router.get('/:id', variousMiddleware, getUserDetails);
router.put('/:id', variousMiddleware, updateUser);

module.exports = router;
```

then you will be able to handle GET and PUT requests.

Another alternative would be to change your "/:id" route to something specifically meant to handle your RESTful operations.  Something like:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', variousMiddleware, login);
router.get('/data/:id', variousMiddleware, getUserDetails);
router.put('/data/:id', variousMiddleware, updateUser);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I don't want to do that. I only want `POST` to be available for `/v1/user/login`. I want the GET and PUT to `/v1/user/login` to return 404.

Comment: Makes sense.  But then your GET /v1/user/login and PUT /v1/user/login are being correctly handled falling through to the respective '/:id' routes.  If you want to make a special case for GET /v1/user/login and PUT /v1/user/login that doesn't fall through to '/:id', then you'd still have to add the handlers as I've indicated and possibly have them just output an error code/message

Comment: Yeah, but that would be an ugly solution, since I already have a 404 handler on a more global level. Wouldn't want to have 404 handlers everywhere.

Comment: Typically you wouldn't.  But you said specifically you wanted to avoid having express letting these specific routes fall through to '/:id'. The question is why do you want to handle GET /v1/user/login and PUT /v1/user/login at all?  All of your login requests should be via POST

Comment: I *don't* want to handle them in any particular way - I want them to return 404. We have tests, which expect `GET` and `POST` to `/v1/user/login` to produce 404, and they are failing (since other errors are produced, like missing parameters, etc.).

Comment: Right, but you are defining a route in '/:id' which is telling your application not to let GET and POST to /v1/user/login produce 404s.  

See edit, you can change your '/:id' route so that it won't act as a catch all for everything under '/v1/user/'

Comment: I think I found a better way that won't change the design of the API - using a regexp to limit the values that `:id` would accept, like so: `router.get('/:id([a-f0-9]+)', variousMiddleware, getUserDetails);`